# How can 64-bit pointer fit into 4 bytes in x86_64 assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm currently reading following blog to understand how to write assembler programs. I understand everything in a blog, but I can't figure one thing.

https://www.recurse.com/blog/7-understanding-c-by-learning-assembly

Code:

```
0x0000000100000f50 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000100000f51 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100000f54 <main+4>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000100000f59 <main+9>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
```

I don't understand why we can write zero to -0x4(%rbp). On the line 1 we pushed pointer saved in register %rbp on a stack. Since %rbp register size is 64-bit I would later expect we would have to write zero to position -0x8(%rbp) in a stack and not -0x4(%rbp), which is only 4 bytes (32-bits).

Can anyone explain that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not storing a 64 bit register, you are storing a 32 bit constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `%rsp` and `%rbp` are equal at this point, `-0x4(%rbp)` is *below* the stack pointer, in the red zone.  This is an area untouched by signal handlers (and debuggers), so it can be used even though it is below the stack pointer.

And the `movl` instruction stores an `int`, a 32-bit quantity, not a 64-bit machine word.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So movl instruction writes to addreses from -0x0(%rbp) to -0x4(%rbp)? I previously thought it writes to addresses from -0x4(%rbp) to -0x8(%rbp). Also what would happen if we pushed something to stack after that?

Comment: @oliva5 `movl` always writes four bytes.  It's `movq` that writes 8 bytes.  If you push something on the stack afterwards, it gets pushed, overwriting whatever you moved there before. There is no special behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @oliva5 the `movl` writes to addresses `rpb-4` to `rbp-1` .. the `rbp-0` already contains first byte of the old `rbp` value pushed by `push rbp` instruction. -4 -3 -2 -1 are four bytes.